# Access json in-file values from multiple sources

Tags: json, caching, redis, scalability

**Background**

I have a json file with max-depth of 1 which means that it basically contains key-value all the way.
The key is, for example, some id and the value is an array of numbers.
e.g: {"1": [1,2,3], "2": [5,4,7,8]}

We upload a new file every x(at the moment, x = 4) days. In each version keys and values might differ from their predecessors. File size could be a couple of GBs. There are occasions where we would like to append data to the json file, and thats important we will be able to do so.
There are numerous files we need to be available all together, some files may replace others (versions).

Now, we're working with AWS and my entire deployment is there, i'm not limited to any of its services.
I would like to somehow host the file and request value by key, like a dictionary, from multiple EC2 instances I have.

My EC2s are plain RESTapi written in .netcore 3.1 and connected to a MongoDb database.

**The issue**

The technologies I thought about using and the reason I won't.

1. MongoDb. Well, the problems here start from the beginning, the json file might contain million of rows, and since we upload a new file once in x days, removing/updating millions of rows is inefficient in both bandwidth, connections and storage. Also, requesting the values in high concurrency can lead to connection starvation, and this DB is used to serve the server which serves the application we have. MongoDb is expensive and its not the best use-case for it.
2. Redis. Since Redis in AWS requires memory to be defined in step 1, the system won't be scalable enough in case of high burst of new keys,values (which basically mean heavier json files). Moreover, Inserting the Redis would require bulk insert, which in this case won't have any expiration (since it doesn't support such). In addition to that, if I won't use expiration there is a point in time where the Redis will have to withstand twice of the size of a json (previous + current, then deleting previous). Other than that, Redis is perfect.
3. MongoDb DataLake, Serve time are extremely slow, each request to our server usually takes less than 3ms of processing (including DB requests), adding DataLake will increase it by 200ms which is disproportionate.
4. Local cache. the main problem is when we will be required to append data to the file, it needs to be available to all other servers and they will have to append their data as well, which will lead, eventually, to data synchronisation issues.

Please tell me if I forgot to add anything or you have any more questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this `Redis would require bulk insert, which in this case won't have any expiration` ?

Comment: @GuyKorland Redis has an option of BulkInsert, but you cannot state the expiration of the objects.
So in order to do that, you either have to delete the predecessor file AFTER adding the new or trying to replace values 1 by 1. in both ways, this might require millions of requests and to do that right, it would take a lot of time per update, bangwidth and general availability

Comment: I'm not aware of BulkInsert command in Redis, which client are you using? Anyway Redis does have an EXPIRE command that allow you to set the TTL on each key.